# How to reimplement PHP 7.3 array sorting method in C#?

Tags: c#, sorting

I am facing an 3rd party API endpoint, which is written in PHP running under PHP 7.3, that is sorting request parameters and computes a SHA signature of it (excl. signature parameter itself) that have to match the one I provide within the request parameters.

Here is an PHP example code of the sorting:

```
$sort_case_sensitive = true;
$keys = array_keys($parameters);
$keys_to_sort = array();
foreach ($keys as $key)
{
    $keys_to_sort[] = $sort_case_sensitive
                  ? $key
                  : strtoupper( $key );
}

array_multisort( $keys_to_sort, SORT_STRING, $keys );
```

The outcome of this PHP function is something like this:

```
address_street
address_street2
address_street_name
address_street_number
```

However, my client is written in C#, and the sorted (default algorithm) output looks like the following:

```
address_street
address_street_name
address_street_number
address_street2
```

How to reimplement PHP's sorting algorithm in C#? I could not find a reference for the alphabet PHP is using for the sort. I can see calls to `zend_binary_strcasecmp_l` for the string sort in PHPs source code, but I could not find the definition of `zend_binary_strcasecmp_l`, just headers.

Comment: Zend is now [laminas](https://getlaminas.org/) apparently, and it says it's open source. Perhaps you can find a clue in that project's source (as opposed to PHP's). Anyway, are you sure your bug isn't in the C#? You haven't shown us how you implemented it. The Zend function you're referring to appears (from its name) to be related to doing case comparisons...but your example results are all lowercase, so case comparisons shouldn't affect it. Seems to be more related to whether it considers numbers to come before or after numeric characters?

Comment: Do you have an example of it sorting uppercase? Given `var q = new string[] { "address_street", "address_street2", "address_street_name", "address_street_number" };`, both `Array.Sort(q, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);` and `Array.Sort(q, StringComparer.Ordinal);` give the result shown.

Comment: @AndrewMorton : `$sort_case_sensitive` is always `true` for the API version I use. So there is no uppercase sorting in my project. And when I manually "fix" the query (reorder manually), I get the signature, the PHP is looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Ordinal comparer:

```
var l = new List<string>();

l.Add("address_street_name");
l.Add("address_street_number");
l.Add("address_street");
l.Add("address_street2");

l.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal);

foreach(string s in l) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/GI7JnM

Comment: I had used `l.Sort()`. With `l.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal);`, the result is as expected. Thank you.